# Error in importing PIRT( Python Image Registration Toolkit) in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, cython, cythonize

So, i have install the PIRT package for image registration. But i am not able to import it in my python. It is showing some error :

```
>>> import pirt
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/osboxes/pirt/pirt/__init__.py", line 36, in <module>
    from . import interp
  File "/home/osboxes/pirt/pirt/interp/__init__.py", line 34, in <module>
    from . import interpolation_
ImportError: No module named 'interpolation_'
```

when i take look to **init**.py file the line it show error on are import interp_ and import interpolation_. However these files are present in my current directory from where it is importing them.

```
osboxes@osboxes:~/pirt/pirt/interp$ ls
func.py      __init__.py~      interpolation_.pxd   interpolation_.pyx  sliceinvolume.py
__init__.py  interpolation_.c  interpolation_.pxd~  __pycache__
```

now i don't understand why importing pirt from the python doesn't work. I am using python 3.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note :

it got solved by just building with

```
python setup.py build_ext --inplace
```

Comment: this builds it `-- inplace` i.e it creates the `.so` object in the current directory and doesn't perform a system wide install (by essentially having the `.so` file in a directory `python` always looks in). If you're just trying ou `pirt` then this is the option to use, if you want to use `pirt` in general, opt with `setup.py install` instead.

Comment: yes i have done that . i initially build with python setup.py build_ext --inplace and went on installing with setup.py.